# DeadObject Exception occured. V7 smart pos Terminal

Tags: java, android, thermal-printer, printer-control-language

I working in V7 POS Terminal(Printing Module) android Machine(V5.1.1). I Have configured the SDK (Jar file) in My application. Server Application is Installed the POS Machine. The Problem occurred during the print. Here I have included my steps. I am stuck  in the Problem  more than a Day. Help me fix it.

**Service Started.**

```
public void startService(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.justtide.service.dev.AIDL_SERVICE");
    intent.setPackage("com.justtide.service.dev");
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

**Device Provider**

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDeviceProvider = DeviceProvider.Stub.asInterface(service);

    }
};
```

**Printer Provider**

```
printerProvider =mDeviceProvider.getPrinterProvider();

printerProvider.fillStringFormat("TEST",PRINTER_FONT_SIZE_SMALL,PRINTER_FONT_TYPE_BOLD,PRINTER_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
printerProvider.fillString("001420183990573");
int ret=-1;
try{
     ret =  printerProvider.print(); //  The Problem is occurred here.
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I have included my Error Logs in POS Machine.

**Error Selected Application**

```
com.example.justtidev7_demo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3e9ea6fc time:3027349
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err: android.os.DeadObjectException
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err:     at com.justtide.service.dev.aidl.printer.PrinterProvider$Stub$Proxy.print(PrinterProvider.java:274)
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err:     at 
com.justtide.dao.Printer.print(Printer.java:34)
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err:     at 
com.justtide.activity.PrintActivity$3.run(PrintActivity.java:111)
com.example.justtidev7_demo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Error No Filter**

```
    JustD: jdc_connect ...
02-08 15:36:51.577 15261-15276/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote 
exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method printerOpen()I in class 
Lcom/just/api/PosDevice; or its super classes (declaration of 
'com.just.api.PosDevice' appears in 
/system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex) at 
com.justtide.justtide.aq.d(Unknown Source) at justtide.PrintPicture.startPrint(Unknown Source) at com.justtide.service.dev.i.print(Unknown Source) at com.justtide.service.dev.aidl.printer.PrinterProvider$Stub.onTransact(Unknown Source) at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
02-08 15:36:51.577 15261-15276/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder_1
Process: com.justtide.service.dev, PID: 15261
                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method printerOpen()I in class Lcom/just/api/PosDevice; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.just.api.PosDevice' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
                                                   at com.justtide.justtide.aq.d(Unknown Source)
                                                   at justtide.PrintPicture.startPrint(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.justtide.service.dev.i.print(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.justtide.service.dev.aidl.printer.PrinterProvider$Stub.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's been over a year, but hey ... let me try to answer this for
>   future readers

Well, for starters the exception `DeadObjectException` simply means that the object you are calling **has died**, because its hosting process no longer exists.

I can see that you did not unbind your connection and you are probably using a connection that is already dead, yet you are calling the print function on it. (You are leaking it, check your logs)

And I would recommend that you try catch all the statements from `PrinterProvider` and start a printer connection on your **Application** class file (i.e `class App extends Application`) expose that object and establish a static connection then use that in your activities, That way you can bind and unbind only once when needed or when exiting an activity.

```
public class App extends Application {
    protected App app;
    public static DeviceProvider deviceProvider;
    public static PrinterProvider printerProvider;
    public static UtilsProvider utils;

    private static ServiceConnection conn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        this.app = (App) getApplicationContext();
    }

    /* do your thing i.e connection, 
    * static methods for printing e.t.c expose them , 
    * use them in your activities
    */

}
```

Or if any of this does not make any sense , you can always ask for a well documented SDK from the manufacturer.

Hope this helps someone.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have fixed the issue with the help of  manufacturer support.